# Confused with github action and ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, github-actions

This is my github actions flow:

```
---
name: build and push image to aws ecr
on:
  push: 
    branches: [ main ]
jobs:
  build-and-push:
    name: Build and push to ecr
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    ...

  deploy:
    needs: build-and-push
    name: deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Login ec2
        env:
          PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.EC2_SSH_KEY }}
          HOSTNAME: ${{ secrets.HOST_DNS }}
          USER_NAME: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        run: |
          echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" > private_key && chmod 600 private_key
          ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i private_key ${USER_NAME}@${HOSTNAME}
          ls
          touch helloworld.txt
```

I wonder that I'm connected to the EC2 instance or not.
This is my result after actions, it's list all file of my project. I think I didn't ssh to EC2 successfull becuase I just create EC2 instance and it's empty.

```
Run echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" > private_key && chmod 600 private_key
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Warning: Permanently added '***,18.181.220.91' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Dockerfile
README.md
docker-compose.yml
nest-cli.json
package-lock.json
package.json
private_key
src
test
tsconfig.build.json
tsconfig.json
```

This is [reference](https://farhan-tanvir.medium.com/ci-cd-from-github-to-aws-ec2-using-github-action-e18b621c0507)

This is my command to ssh ec2 from client: ssh -i "home-key.pem" ec2-user@ec2-18-181-220-91.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com

If i didn't connnect to EC2 instance,  how I do it with github ?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder that I'm connected to the EC2 instance or not.

In your SSH commands, add a `hostname -a` one: it will display the name of the machine you are on.

That being said, you could use [`actions/ssh-execute-commands`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/ssh-execute-commands) to execute those same commands:

```yaml
- name: Execute SSH commmands on remote server
  uses: JimCronqvist/action-ssh@master
  env:
    PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.EC2_SSH_KEY }}
    HOSTNAME: ${{ secrets.HOST_DNS }}
    USER_NAME: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
  with:
    hosts: '${USER_NAME}@${HOSTNAME}'
    privateKey: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
    debug: false
    command: |
      ls -lah
      hostname -a
      whoami
      touch helloworld.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you save my day, it is said that ec2-user

Comment: @ĐoànĐứcBảo Perfect, well done!